# C# Web Service Call (asmx) over SSL with wildcard certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, ssl

I am making a web service call from a windows service.  The web service is to use SSL so the url to the webservice is https://myclient.mydomain.com:4443/app/webservices/webservice.asmx

4443 is being used instead of 443 for other reasons.

I can browse to this URL and it works fine.  The certificate is purchased from GlobalSign and is a wildcard certificate *.mydomain.com

There are no issues browsering to the webservice.

When I make the call from the windows service it's not working.  Using System.Net.Trace I was able to get the below information.  While browsers work fine it seems .NET doesn't work correctly with wildcard certificates.  Has anyone else experienced this?

```
[Subject]
  CN=*.mydomain.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
  Simple Name: *.mydomain.com
  DNS Name: mydomain.com

[Issuer]
  CN=AlphaSSL CA - G2, O=AlphaSSL
  Simple Name: AlphaSSL CA - G2
  DNS Name: AlphaSSL CA - G2

System.Net Information: 0 : [2688] SecureChannel#48611003 - Remote certificate has errors:
    ProcessId=8676
    DateTime=2014-08-21T20:58:13.4998725Z

System.Net Information: 0 : [2688] SecureChannel#48611003 -     Certificate name mismatch.
    ProcessId=8676
    DateTime=2014-08-21T20:58:13.4998725Z

System.Net Information: 0 : [2688] SecureChannel#48611003 - Remote certificate was verified as invalid by the user.
    ProcessId=8676
    DateTime=2014-08-21T20:58:13.4998725Z

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [2688] Socket#31879635::Dispose()
    ProcessId=8676
    DateTime=2014-08-21T20:58:13.4998725Z

System.Net Error: 0 : [2688] Exception in HttpWebRequest#10189992:: - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel..
    ProcessId=8676
    DateTime=2014-08-21T20:58:13.4998725Z
```

-- UPDATE 1 --

Ok partically resolved.  I had forgotten we put in code to convert all host names to IP addresses which was causing the name mismatch.  This url https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/872612/net-web-service-call-stuck-in-infinite-loop-due-to-exception-in-system-net-sockets describes why we did this because of errors in .NET we were gettin when windows is set to IPv6 preferred.

I've removed this host name to IP address conversion but now it won't connect at all now and am getting System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [5788] Exception in Socket#31879635::EndConnect - A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 173.78.224.118:4443. even though the connection attempt it to the url with the host name and we can browse from the machine to that ip and host name url with a browser.

-- UPDATE 2 --

Now determined works ok on Windows 7 but not working with Windows 8.1 getting the socket operation error.  Funny part the Windows 7 is a VM running on the Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to call the web service from code, and that's where you're getting the certificate error? You mention a data service, is this the code from where you are trying to call the HTTPS web service?

Comment: Yes windows server (sorry I called it data service habbit because that's what we call it in the office) written in C# calling a web service (asmx) written in C# over HTTS using port 4443 (not 443)  The System.Net.Trace log file is what I included above where it is saying the certificate name mismatch when we use the url myclient.mydomain.com and the certificate is for *.mydomain.com

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a self-signed wildcard certificate? Also, can you include the code that configures and calls the ASMX web service? I haven't seen or heard of any issues with .NET, ASMX and wildcard carts before, so I'm leaning towards a configuration issue.

Comment: I'll work with the server admin on that, we are also going to try a free 90 trial certificate that is directly for the domain we are using rather then a wildcard one to help rule that out.

Comment: Also if I use a selfsigned one I would expect it to fail as well for not being trusted (I guess I could confirm it fails for a different reason).

Comment: For the self signed wildcard, you would have to add the authority to the local machine cert store, yes. The idea would be to check if the certificate is at fault or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like this..

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    //evaluate cert and return true if its ok
    return true;
});
```

Put that block of code somewhere in your app before you open the service client.

Comment: Your recommendation along with the rest of the internet's recommendation to IGNORE the fact that the certificate is invalid is infact a very very bad practice.

Comment: @ChrisWard I am not recommending that you ignore the cert, I am recommending that you handle the error by applying logic in the proper place.

Comment: If you read my updates the cert is not an issue now.  The issue now is that it doesn't work on Windows 8.1